# Rails using mysql2 instead of sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following configuration:

- linux ubuntu 11.04
- rails 3.0.9
- ruby 1.9.2p290
- mysql2 (0.2.7)

I have created first my project using "rails new"
then I have modified the Gemfile to use mysql2 version 0.2.7 (I have read that later versions are working with rails 3.1 only) 
Then I changed the file database.yml to use mysql2 instead of sqlite3
But now I'm getting error **ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished** when I try to connect to a Controller. Here are the full logs:

```
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:317:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/server.rb:217:in `start'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:30
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:27
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

PS: I tried almost all solutions provided in this website, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: I forgot to tell that the db:schema:load seems to be working :`rake db:schema:load
-- create_table("areas", {:force=>true})
   -> 1.7675s
-- create_table("properties", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0399s`

Comment: What does your database.yml file look like? Which version of MySQL have you installed?

Comment: here is the dev part: `development:
 adapter: mysql2
 database: db/dev.hoha
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000`

Comment: Normally the database.yml for mysql2 has username, password and host fields too. Also, your database name looks weird - I'm not sure a "/" is allowed (I've never seen it like that before).

Comment: I have changed the database name and created a new mysql user with password. I confirm that the rake db:migrate and the tables are created in the mysql database. but I still have the same issue (ConnectionNotEstablished)

Comment: Did you run bundle? and installed all  gems ?

Comment: Yes I have ran "bundle install"! I'm really blocked. I don't understand the meaning of the logs, no cause is shown :(

Comment: I ended by recreating a new project with the command

rails new -d mysql

And now the pages are retrieved without any problem! I tried to compare the automatic database.yml file and the manual one, the only diffrence I have noticed was on the user used for mysql database. in the new one the username: root is used. I came back to the old project and I changed to username/password with root ones I now it is working!!!

Answer (score 2):

I ended by recreating a new project with the command

rails new  -d mysql

And now the pages are retrieved without any problem! 
I tried to compare the automatic database.yml file and the manual one, the only diffrence I have noticed was on the user used for mysql database. in the new one the username: root is used. 
I came back to the old project and I changed to username/password with root ones I now it is working!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your database.yml file is incorrect.  It should look something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost 
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
```

If that doesn't work, try changing localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: I have changed the database name and created a new mysql user with password. I confirm that the rake db:migrate and the tables are created in the mysql database. but I still have the same issue (ConnectionNotEstablished)